# Find total count of documents matching a specific condition in nested sub document array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection of documents that contain matches to be played from different bookies.

```
 [
    {
        "_id": "5b83e6340818897dc988f57d",
        "pseudoKey": "hannover-dortmund",
        "sport": "Soccer",
        "league": "Bundesliga",
        "date": "2018-08-31T18:30:00.000Z",
        "team1": "Hannover",
        "team2": "Dortmund",
        "matchInstances": [
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Hannover",
                    "price": "5.41"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Dortmund",
                    "price": "1.57"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "hannover-dortmund",
                "service": "Sportpesa",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.44",
                "url": "https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/games/1427914/markets?league=76390&top=1&sid=3679&sportId=1"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Hannover",
                    "price": "5.65"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Dortmund",
                    "price": "1.53"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "hannover-dortmund",
                "service": "Betika",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.58",
                "url": "https://www.betika.com/mobile/dist/#/prebets/markets/542303"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Hannover",
                    "price": "6"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Dortmund",
                    "price": "1.57"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "hannover-dortmund",
                "service": "1XBet",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.8",
                "url": "https://1xbet.co.ke/en/line/Football/96463-Germany-Bundesliga/28884025-Hannover-96-Borussia-Dortmund/"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Hannover",
                    "price": "5.75"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Dortmund",
                    "price": "1.49"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "hannover-dortmund",
                "service": "Betpawa",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.85",
                "url": "https://www.betpawa.co.ke/event-458477-hannover-96-borussia-dortmund"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b83e6340818897dc988f578",
        "pseudoKey": "nurnberg-mainz",
        "sport": "Soccer",
        "league": "Bundesliga",
        "date": "2018-09-01T13:30:00.000Z",
        "team1": "Nurnberg",
        "team2": "Mainz",
        "matchInstances": [
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Nurnberg",
                    "price": "2.42"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Mainz",
                    "price": "3.18"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "nurnberg-mainz",
                "service": "Sportpesa",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "3.12",
                "url": "https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/games/1428636/markets?league=76390&top=1&sid=1835&sportId=1"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Nurnberg",
                    "price": "2.39"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Mainz",
                    "price": "3.19"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "nurnberg-mainz",
                "service": "Betika",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "3.15",
                "url": "https://www.betika.com/mobile/dist/#/prebets/markets/542710"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Nurnberg",
                    "price": "2.49"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Mainz",
                    "price": "3.38"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "nurnberg-mainz",
                "service": "1XBet",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "3.18",
                "url": "https://1xbet.co.ke/en/line/Football/96463-Germany-Bundesliga/28235773-1.-Nurnberg-1.-FSV-Mainz-05/"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Nurnberg",
                    "price": "2.30"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Mainz",
                    "price": "3.15"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "nurnberg-mainz",
                "service": "Betpawa",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "3.30",
                "url": "https://www.betpawa.co.ke/event-458949-nurnberg-mainz-05"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b83e6340818897dc988f583",
        "pseudoKey": "leverkusen-wolfsburg",
        "sport": "Soccer",
        "league": "Bundesliga",
        "date": "2018-09-01T13:30:00.000Z",
        "team1": "Leverkusen",
        "team2": "Wolfsburg",
        "matchInstances": [
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Leverkusen",
                    "price": "1.68"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Wolfsburg",
                    "price": "4.81"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "leverkusen-wolfsburg",
                "service": "Sportpesa",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.11",
                "url": "https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/games/1428638/markets?league=76390&top=1&sid=1155&sportId=1"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Leverkusen",
                    "price": "1.63"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Wolfsburg",
                    "price": "4.99"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "leverkusen-wolfsburg",
                "service": "Betika",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.22",
                "url": "https://www.betika.com/mobile/dist/#/prebets/markets/542711"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Leverkusen",
                    "price": "1.68"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Wolfsburg",
                    "price": "5.4"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "leverkusen-wolfsburg",
                "service": "1XBet",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.3",
                "url": "https://1xbet.co.ke/en/line/Football/96463-Germany-Bundesliga/28235769-Bayer-04-Leverkusen-VfL-Wolfsburg/"
            },
            {
                "team1": {
                    "name": "Leverkusen",
                    "price": "1.62"
                },
                "team2": {
                    "name": "Wolfsburg",
                    "price": "4.85"
                },
                "pseudoKey": "leverkusen-wolfsburg",
                "service": "Betpawa",
                "region": "Kenya",
                "drawPrice": "4.40",
                "url": "https://www.betpawa.co.ke/event-458936-bayer-leverkusen-wolfsburg"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7689bc6c947619191879d7"),
    "pseudoKey" : "nimes-marseille",
    "sport" : "Soccer",
    "league" : "Ligue 1",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-08-19T19:00:00.000Z"),
    "team1" : "Nimes",
    "team2" : "Marseille",
    "matchInstances" : [ 
        {
            "team1" : {
                "name" : "Nimes",
                "price" : "4.45"
            },
            "team2" : {
                "name" : "Marseille",
                "price" : "1.74"
            },
            "pseudoKey" : "nimes-marseille",
            "service" : "Betin",
            "region" : "Kenya",
            "drawPrice" : "4.00",
            "url" : "https://web.betin.co.ke/Sport/SubEventOdds.aspx?SubEventID=18398860"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 29 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7689bc6c947619191879d8"),
    "pseudoKey" : "nantes-caen",
    "sport" : "Soccer",
    "league" : "Ligue 1",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-08-25T18:00:00.000Z"),
    "team1" : "Nantes",
    "team2" : "Caen",
    "matchInstances" : [ 
        {
            "team1" : {
                "name" : "Nantes",
                "price" : "1.85"
            },
            "team2" : {
                "name" : "Caen",
                "price" : "4.65"
            },
            "pseudoKey" : "nantes-caen",
            "service" : "Betin",
            "region" : "Kenya",
            "drawPrice" : "3.40",
            "url" : "https://web.betin.co.ke/Sport/SubEventOdds.aspx?SubEventID=18431759"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 30 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7689bc6c947619191879d9"),
    "pseudoKey" : "marseille-rennes",
    "sport" : "Soccer",
    "league" : "Ligue 1",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-08-26T19:00:00.000Z"),
    "team1" : "Marseille",
    "team2" : "Rennes",
    "matchInstances" : [ 
        {
            "team1" : {
                "name" : "Marseille",
                "price" : "1.65"
            },
            "team2" : {
                "name" : "Rennes",
                "price" : "5.30"
            },
            "pseudoKey" : "marseille-rennes",
            "service" : "Betin",
            "region" : "Kenya",
            "drawPrice" : "3.90",
            "url" : "https://web.betin.co.ke/Sport/SubEventOdds.aspx?SubEventID=18431757"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
    ...
    ]
```

I want to get the total count of Bundesliga matches.I have used the aggregation pipeline `$unwind` and `$group` stages

```
db.getCollection('matches').aggregate({ $unwind : "$matchInstances" },
    { $group: {
        _id: '',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
})
```

Am getting the total count of all matches in all leagues instead.

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "count" : 373.0
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in the given snippets you never specify the league you want, is there something you forgot ?

Comment: Could you possibly point out where i could be doing wrong?Or what am missing?

Comment: I don't know anything about mongoDB reading the doc :p, but maybe you could add a selector after `db.getCollection('matches')` maybe something like `whereEquals('league', 'Bundesliga')`(<-- not actual mongoDB do not use)

Comment: @matthPen answer's use the correct syntax for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@matthPenn.Changed the syntax slightly

```
  db.getCollection('matches').aggregate([{$match:{"league":"Bundesliga"}},{ $unwind : "$matchInstances" },
    { $group: {
       _id:'',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add $match stage as first stage, to filter docs by league before unwind.

```
db.getCollection('matches').aggregate(
    {$match:{"league":"Bundesliga"}},
    { $unwind : "$matchInstances" },
    { $group: {
            _id: '',
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    })
```

Comment: @matthPenn Correct but with slight syntax change